# MongoDB Array Search in Query or client side

Tags: php, mongodb

I am wondering what is better to do. I have a pulled back a query like this:

```
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 4eeedd9545c717620a000007
    )
[field1] => ...
[field2] => ...
[field3] => ...
[field4] => ...
[field5] => ...
[field6] => ...

[votes] => Array
    (
        [whoVoted] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4f98930cb1445d0a7d000001
                [1] => 4f98959cb1445d0a7d000002
                [1] => 4f88730cb1445d0a7d000003
            )

    )

)
```

Which would be faster:

1. Pull that entire array in 1 query and use `in_array()` to find the right id?
2. Pull everything from the first query except the votes and then do another mongodb query to see if that id exist in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Depends on a lot of factors that I suggest you test but IMO most of the time it would be faster to just do 2 querys

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the array being returned / searched.

Also different servers are doing the work, what do you mean by faster? At what scale?

Comment: right now the array is 200 but I expect it to jump up to more like 10,000. yes at scale